# SQL Server MERGE returns error message 8672

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error message and have no idea how to debug it.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @CurMonth int
DECLARE @CurYear int
DECLARE @Date datetime

SET @Date = DATEADD(m, -1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
SET @CurMonth = MONTH(@Date)
SET @CurYear = YEAR(@Date)

EXEC Tablename.dbo.ps_ProcedureTable1 @CurMonth, @CurYear


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ps_ProcedureTable1]
(
    @CurMonth int,
    @CurYear int
) 
AS
MERGE
    Tablename.dbo.table1 AS target
USING
    (SELECT
        a.Ti, a.G, a.A, a.R, a.D, a.U,
        a.FullName, a.W,
        a.SDay, a.EDay, a.HDay,
        a.C, a.QC, a.FC, a.CH, a.TH, a.FH,
        a.LH, a.TtH, a.WKH, a.Va, a.Tr,
        a.OT, a.Other, a.M, a.P, a.Ve,
        a.SCa, a.HWK, a.AHr, a.SPF, a.AfTl,
        a.TtHC, a.WKHRs, a.Days, a.ISWD,
        a.HInD, a.OT, a.RT, a.HrSt, a.Sk
     FROM Tablename.dbo.vw_Table1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
     WHERE MONTH(a.W) = @CurMonth AND YEAR(a.W) = @CurYear) AS Source 
         ON Source.U = Target.U AND Source.W = Target.W

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        SDay = Source.SDay,
        EDay = Source.EDay,
        HDay = Source.HDay,
        C = Source.C,
        QC = Source.QC,
        FC = Source.FC,
        CH = Source.CH,
        TH = Source.TH,
        FH = Source.FH,
        LH = Source.LH,
        TtH = Source.TtH,
        WKH = Source.WKH,
        Va = Source.Va,
        Tr = Source.Tr,
        OT = Source.OT,
        Other = Source.Other,
        M = Source.M,
        P = Source.P,
        Ve = Source.Ve,
        SCa = Source.SCa,
        HWK = Source.HWK,
        AHr = Source.AHr,
        SPF = Source.SPF,
        AfTl = Source.AfTl,
        TtHC = Source.TtHC,
        WKHRs = Source.WKHRs,
        Days = Source.Days,
        ISWD = Source.ISWD,
        HInD = Source.HInD,
        OT = Source.OT,
        RT = Source.RT,
        HrSt = Source.HrSt,
        Sk = Source.Sk

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Ti, G, A, R, D, U,
            FullName, W, SDay, EDay, HDay,
            C, QC, FC, CH, TH, FH, LH,
            TtH, WKH, Va, Tr, OT, Other,
            M, P, Ve, SCa, HWK, AHr, SPF,
            AfTl, TtHC, WKHRs, Days, ISWD, HInD,
            OT, RT, HrSt, Sk)
    VALUES (Source.Ti, Source.G, Source.A, Source.R, Source.D, Source.U,
            Source.FullName, Source.W, Source.SDay, Source.EDay, Source.HDay,
            Source.C, Source.QC, Source.FC, Source.CH, Source.TH, Source.FH, Source.LH,
            Source.TtH, Source.WKH, Source.Va, Source.Tr, Source.OT, Source.Other,
            Source.M, Source.P, Source.Ve, Source.SCa, Source.HWK, Source.AHr, Source.SPF,
            Source.AfTl, Source.TtHC, Source.WKHRs, Source.Days, Source.ISWD, Source.HInD,
            Source.OT, Source.RT, Source.HrSt, Source.Sk);
GO
```

I'm getting this error message.

> Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ps_EAGenerateWorkHours, Line 12
>   The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.
>   Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

I've looked and researched online but just can't figure out what is wrong with my codes.

Comment: I think that the error message is very clear: `This happens when a target row matches more than one source row`, so, your `Source.U=Target.U  AND Source.W=Target.W` gives multiple results

Comment: And get rid of that NOLOCK hint or this error will show up randomly because when you query with hint it can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

Merge query execution will return 'duplicate rows' error if

```
SELECT U, W, count(*)
 FROM Tablename.dbo.vw_Table1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
 WHERE MONTH(a.W) = @CurMonth AND YEAR(a.W) = @CurYear
 group by    U, W
 having count(*)>1
```

or

```
SELECT U, W, count(*)
 FROM Tablename.dbo.table1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
 group by    U, W
 having count(*)>1
```

return any rows

one of these query returns duplicate rows based on 'on clause' of merge query